# Trig / javascript to calculate padding required to accommodate image rotation without clipping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, geometry, trigonometry

I have a known rect (grey) the outer parent element that contains an image element (orange). It's overflow is hidden.

I want to calculate the padding required to allow the image element(known width and height) to be rotated to a known angle (for this e.g. lets say 30 degrees).

It has proven to be relatively easy to calculate this if i were able to allow the parent(grey) element to expand to accommodate, but i can't.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. create list of 4 image edge points `p0,p1,p2,p3`
2. rotate them the same way as the image will be rotated

   ```
   double   a=x-x0,b=y-y0,c,s;
   c=cos(alfa);
   s=sin(alfa);
   x=a*c-b*s+x0;
   y=a*s+b*c+y0;
   ```

   - `x,y` is the point
   - `x0,y0` is center of rotation
   - `alfa` is the rotation angle
3. compute min,max of rotated points x,y coordinates this gets you the bounding box
4. summary

   - let `(x0,y0)` be the original image gray box size `(X,Y)` from your image
   - let `(x1,y1)` be the original image size `(xa,xb)` from your image
   - let `(x2,y2)` be the rotated image bounding box size (xmax-xmin,ymax-ymin) from bullet 3
   - `if ((x2<=x0)&&(y2<=y0))` the image fits so stop
   - let `mx=x0/x2` and `my=y0/y2` be the needed scales to fit the image
   - do not zoom:
   - `if (mx>1.0) mx=1.0;`
   - `if (my>1.0) my=1.0;`
   - now select the correct scale `m`
   - `m=mx; if (m>my) m=my;`
   - now the `m` holds the scale needed to apply on rotated image to fit the gray area
   - do not forget to center the image ...

Comment: This just gets me the larger bounding box that extends beyond the bounds of the grey box. One of my governors, is that the grey box can not be made larger to accommodate the new rotated bounding box. I must add to the bounding box an appropriate amount so the image shrinks the correct amount, instead of increasing the size of the grey box. Subtracting the old bounding box from new bounding box and dividing by 2 to use as padding like this results in too much padding for what will become a smaller image rect after padding applied.

Comment: @GarySimpson now I am lost at what you want to achieve. you want to shrink the rotated image to fit inside original bounding box of image ? or expand gray area so the aspect ratio is constant or what? booth can be computed easily with the new bounding box size ...

Comment: I can't alter grey box. I need to proportionally shrink image by padding grey box an appropriate amount so when image is rotated the given angle points of image do not get clipped by grey box.

Comment: @GarySimpson added bullet 4  to answer

Comment: Thanks. That makes more sense. Calculating the scale factor needed to reduce rotated bounding box to fit inside grey, then applying that to the image. Just hope it ends up being fast enough to be responsive, in the window resize event. But thank you very much for taking the time to nail this concept home.